# Read data from database and store result to DataSet

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to read data from a database and store it to DataSet as result. The point of this is that I want to create a `Report` in DevExpress which contains multiple parameter. When I store data to dataset I want to filter report based on User Input.

```
    public void BindToData(int OrgId, bool Status)
    {
        try
        {
            string connString = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DesignSaoOsig1;Integrated Security=True";
            string strproc = "TestReport";
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(strproc, connString))
            {
                sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Status;
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrgJed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OrgId;

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sda.Fill(ds);
                XtraReport report = new XtraReport();
                report.DataSource = ds;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Button click to run function

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int OrgId = 1;
            bool Status = true;
            BindToData(OrgId,Status);
        }
```

So far this is code which I wrote but when I run it `report.DataSource = ds` doesn't get any result.

When I debug it, I didn't see where the error is.

**Stored Procedure**

```
USE [DesignSaoOsig1]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[TestReport]    Script Date: 29. 5. 2020. 09:20:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestReport]
(           
    @Status bit,
    @OrgJed int
) 
AS  
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 1 OrgUnitID
    FROM    tblZaposleni_AD 
    --WHERE  Status =    @Status AND 
    --  OrgUnitID = @OrgJed  
END
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214885/discussion-on-question-by-dobrosumljivmomak-read-data-from-database-and-store-re).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just run your exact code with a different connection string:

```
        try
        {
            string connString = @"Confidential";
            string strproc = "TestReport";
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(strproc, connString))
            {
                sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = true;
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrgJed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sda.Fill(ds);

                string temp = "123"; // Line to set breakpoint on
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

And it gives me a single table result with a single row as show in the watch window below:

[image]

Note in addition to selecting the id from a table I have selected the input parameters so they are visible and can be checked that what comes out is the same as what went in.